# 401 Unauthorize even after FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I'm trying to implement ASP.NET MVC5 application with basic form authentication.
So there is my login method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string email, string password, bool? rememberMe)
    {
        if (email.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || password.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        UserEntity user = new UserEntity() {Email = email, PasswordHash = password};
        var userFromDb = _userService.FindUser(user);
        if (userFromDb != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userFromDb.Name, rememberMe.GetValueOrDefault());

            var a = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //This is still false for some reson
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But right after this method on redirect it give's me `401 Unauthorized` error.
Also seem's like  HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

Do you have any idea/suggestions why it's like that and how to fix it?

---

UPD: I also have a line webconfig notions for from auth, so that's not a reason

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" />
</authentication>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the reason. For some reason in my webconfig there is a line, which suppress `FormsAuthentication` module

`<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>`

So with this line `FormsAuthentiction` not working, but if we comment it out or delete, all works as expected.

Comment: This is because MVC5 does not use FormsAuthentication by default.  It uses ASP.NET Identity, so it removes FormsAuthentication in the default template.  When you replaced that, you did not re-enable FormsAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Place 
 `<authentication mode="Forms" />` into your web.config file within `<system.web>`for it to trigger its effect.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, so thanks for that!